# C++ Output to both console and file?

Tags: c++, console-application

I have a program written in C++ that I'm trying to debug.

When I wrote the first few versions of my program, I included several cout statements to print to the console so I could debug.  Now, my program's grown to several thousand lines with several hundred cout statements.  I have a rare bug that only occurs if I run the program a few thousand times, so even though my console screen buffer is 9999, I still don't see all of my debugging output.

I know that I could create a file stream and write some code to output to a file under each cout statement, but since I have so many cout statements it would take me a while to do this.

I'm new to C++ so I just wanted to see if anyone knew of a faster alternative before I edit all of my source code.  Thanks.

Edit: I'm running the program on Windows.

Comment: If you're running under linux, a simple `./myprogram > filename` ought to work.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm running the program on Windows.  Now I wish I was running it on Linux :P

Comment: The same thing works on windows.

Comment: On the Windows command line, `myprogram > someFile.txt` works, assuming you are running the command in the same directory where the executable is at.

Comment: Ahh you guys are awesome.  Wish I could up-vote.  Thanks - If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: and `myprogram >> someFile.txt` should append to the same text file when you run the program "a few thousand times"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend changing the source just for that. In Linux (or Cygwin) environment just pipe your output to `tee`. If you don't have `tee` to your disposal, it takes about 20 minutes to write.

*Edit*:
The core of `tee` is

```
FILE * file = fopen("outfilename", "wb");
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
while(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin)) {
    fputs(buffer, stdout);
    fputs(buffer, file);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include in my original question, I'm actually running it on Windows (unfortunately).

Comment: Install Cygwin then. It's a Windows package, and it worths it to have.